# can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, destroy

```py
import random
import string
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

password = 0
window = tk.Tk()
def Manager():
    while True:
        def random_password():
        # get random password

            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
            global password
            password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(8))


        def Button():
            label = tkinter.Label(
                text=password,
                foreground="white",  # Set the text color to white
                background="black",  # Set the background color to black
                width = 20,
            )
            button = tk.Button(
                text='Agian?',
                width = 20,
                bg="blue",
                fg="yellow",
                command=lambda:[window.destroy(), Manager()]
            )
            label.pack()
            button.pack()
            window.mainloop()

        random_password()
        Button()
Manager()
```

I want to get everytime when I press the Button a new password. And this is my Error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oksra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\oksra\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 33, in <lambda>
    command=lambda:[window.destroy(), Manager()]
  File "C:\Users\oksra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2312, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

How I can Fix it?

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier to just update the label with the new value as opposed to destroying and creating a new window, but I did add an answer to fix the error you had.  You will need to look into what happens when the user hits the X button because that will cause the same problem. Simply updating the label would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating your instance of `Tk()` inside the function.  Place the instance of `Tk()` inside the function and it will work. You also should look at changing your import statements to only `import tkinter as tk` and then consistently use that namespace for uniformity. A wildcard `import` should be avoided.  I made the changes below and it should work for you now. You would probably benefit from restructuring this as a `class` instead of the nested functions like you have.

```
import random
import string
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

password = 0

def Manager():
    window = tk.Tk()
    while True:
        def random_password():
        # get random password

            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
            global password
            password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(8))


        def Button():
            label = tk.Label(
                text=password,
                foreground="white",  # Set the text color to white
                background="black",  # Set the background color to black
                width = 20,
            )
            button = tk.Button(
                text='Agian?',
                width = 20,
                bg="blue",
                fg="yellow",
                command=lambda:[window.destroy(), Manager()]
            )
            label.pack()
            button.pack()
            window.mainloop()

        random_password()
        Button()
Manager()
```

---

Consider how much easier this is if you only change the label instead of destroying and creating a new window.

```
import random
import string
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


def generate_password():
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    global password
    password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(8))
    label['text'] = password

    
window = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(window, text="", foreground="white", background="black",
                 width=20)
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(window, text="Generate Password", bg="blue", fg="yellow", width=20,
                   command=generate_password)
button.pack()
    

window.mainloop()
```